# Is Dijkstra's algorithm used in cheapest airfare calculators?

Tags: graphs, optimization, shortest-path

Is Dijkstra's shortest-path graph algorithm used in cheapest airfare calculators like Expedia or CheapAir?

Comment: This is a good question (of which I don't have the answer). It is likely, as the possible roads are not unique. But the optimization could be made either on $ cost or on total time or some other criterion, with a limit on the number of stops.